# Formatting a string in php by converting it

Tags: php

I have a function that is passed on a string in php that i would like to remove ""

The string is "name"  I would like it to be name

I have tried

```
(string)"name";
```

Buy it still returns 'name'

What do i have to do

Comment: What function? What is the actual string? Which `"` you are talking about?

Comment: There are no quotes in your variable value. That's just how var_dump() outputs it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use str_replace function to do that:
for deleting all ' characters for example you can do this:

```
$name="'m'w'a'n'g'i'";
$name = str_replace("'","",$name);
echo $name // prints mwangi
```

it replaces ' character with nothing("") in your $name